# System.Drawing.Bitmap has a null reference or invalid value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am writing an application with .NET 5.0 Visual Studio 2019 and C# to digitize cine film frames in order to generate a video.
I use Accord.Video and Accord.Video.DirectShow to grab the cine film frames using a USB digital microscope. That works well so far.
The grabbed System.Drawing.Bitmap is stored as a static Bitmap for further processing (color adjusting, sharpening etc).
For post-processing I clone the static bitmap.
This also works fine for the first time, but when I try to clone the static Bitmap a second time I get a message, that there is a null reverence or an invalid value and an exception is thrown. The message says: "Object is not in a state that can allow this operation (GDI+ status Wrong status)"
Very likely the invalid value is the "Palette" property. See attached pictures.[the properties of the bitmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Kkd.jpg)

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Without code, its difficult to suggest

Comment: this is a textfile with the failing code.

Class "VideoFrameCather" stores the image read from the microscope METHOD: private void Video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)

Class "ExtractionHandler" method "public void ModifyImage()" tries to read the image from the file. This works one time but the it fails with the error mentioned in the previos note

https://wkurz.com/wkurz/download/ProvidedCodeSnippet.txt

Comment: Please addthe code to the question.